# How do I use serial.available 2 times in this code?

Tags: arduino-ide, arduino-esp8266

```
int input;
int choices;
void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600);

Serial.println("BIN, DEC, HEX, OCT Converter\n");
retry:
Serial.println("Kindly choose a number system to convert (1, 2, 3, 4)");
Serial.println("1. BIN\n2. DEC\n3. HEX\n4. OCT\n");
while (Serial.available() == 0) {}

choices = Serial.parseInt();

if (choices == 1) {
Serial.println("You have chosen BIN, please enter a valid input");
  }
else if (choices == 2) {
Serial.println("You have chosen DEC, please enter a valid input");
  }
else if (choices == 3) {
Serial.println("You have choses HEX, please enter a valid input");
  }
else if (choices == 4) {
Serial.println("You have chosen OCT, please enter a valid input");
  }
else {
Serial.println("Invalid choice."); \
goto retry;
  }

switch (choices) {
case 1: while (Serial.available() == 0) {}
  input = Serial.parseInt();
  Serial.print("You have input ");
  Serial.print(input);
  break;
case 2: while (Serial.available() == 0) {}
  input = Serial.parseInt();
  Serial.print("You have input ");
  Serial.print(input);
  break;
  }

  }
  void loop() {
  }
```

In the part `switch`, when I run the code, it shows only 0 and it doesn't give me the option to enter at the serial monitor again.

I can't seem to figure this out, I'm a beginner who's trying to improve in the semantics of Arduino IDE. Thank you

Comment: The [documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/parseint/) states "If no valid digits were read when the time-out (see Serial.setTimeout()) occurs, 0 is returned". Also, you don't really know when the first input end and the second begins. I would not recommend using `Serial.parseInt()`. Use a buffer instead and parse from there, that's easier to handle.

Comment: Additionally, you have all your code in `setup()`. This will only ever execute once, so you'll never get back to the beginning (unless you press "reset" on the board)